# Linux Kernel minor number vermagic comparison

Tags: linux, kernel, version, insmod

I have a simple question about modules in the linux kernel.

Is it guaranteed that my compiled module works throughout the whole X.Y kernel release.

X: Kernel version
Y: Major version
Z: Minor version

So for example:

I compile my module.ko with the tree of a 4.9 Kernel.
Then it is possible to `insmod` my module with 4.9.24, 4.9.31,4.9.34,...?

So does the vermagic comparison skip everything after the major number?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/stable-api-nonsense.rst ?

If you want stable ABI you need to target kernels shipped with RHEL or SLES (or their derivatives which claim to maintain the ABI).

Comment: Yes. But i just want to know if it can change between minor versions^^

Comment: most of the time it does not, but as stated in the document there is no guarantee whatsoever

Comment: but how does the vermagic comparison work then?
It doesn't know when something changes...

Comment: `how does the vermagic comparison work then? It doesn't know when something changes.` - Version is generated based on the size of the types, used for function's arguments. So vermagic is able to detect some changes in API.